# Get file names from specified Folder in photoshop Java Script

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop

I am a Photographer, I have very less knowledge of programing.

I have a script which requires three inputs which it plugs into the main function.

1. set the input folder
2. File Names
3. Output Name

please see below

```
            var INPUT_FOLDER = Folder.selectDialog ( "Where are your Images" );
            var FILE_NAMES =  ["image_1" , "image2","image3","image4"];
            var OUTPUT_NAME = "Final Image";
            main(INPUT_FOLDER, FILE_NAMES, OUTPUT_NAME);
```

Question

1. right now as you can see in the script Image names are defined in the script and it becomes extremely difficut to change them everytime.

   is there anyway that it searches the defined folder "INPUT_FOLDER" and loads all the file names in the folder to file names variable ?
2. Also similar to input select dialog, it will be great if we have a output window dialoge aswell (some thing like save window) where we can mention the processed image name and location to save it.

Thanks in Advance.

Any suggestions on this will greatly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var INPUT_FOLDER = Folder.selectDialog ( "Where are your Images" );
// get an array of File objects inside INPUT_FOLDER
var FILES_ARRAY = INPUT_FOLDER.getFiles();
// get a saved file location
var OUTPUT_FILE = File.saveDialog( "Where would you like the image saved?" );
// now call the main function
main(INPUT_FOLDER, FILES_ARRAY, OUTPUT_FILE);
```

Note that the parameter types for main() have changed -- you'll now be passing an array of File objects instead of an array of file names, and the output file, too, is a File object instead of just a name.

You can find more about Photoshop's file scripting support in [Adobe's Javascript Tools Guide](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf).